# Dojo 1.8 grid inside tab

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I'm newbe in Dojo, I just create a layout **index.php** with tab container and a tab calls **list.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: Progammatic Layout</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout"></div>
        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script>
            require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
                 "dijit/layout/TabContainer", 
                 "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
                 "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
                 "dijit/layout/AccordionPane",
                 "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                 "dojox/grid/cells",
                 "dojo/ready", 

                 ],
            function(BorderContainer, TabContainer,ContentPane, AccordionContainer, AccordionPane, DataGrid, gridCells, ready){
                ready(function(){
                    // create the BorderContainer and attach it to our appLayout div
                    var appLayout = new BorderContainer({
                        design: "headline"
                    }, "appLayout");


                    // create the TabContainer
                    var contentTabs = new TabContainer({
                        region: "center",
                        id: "contentTabs",
                        tabPosition: "bottom",
                        "class": "centerPanel"
                    });

                    // add the TabContainer as a child of the BorderContainer
                    appLayout.addChild( contentTabs );

                    // create and add the BorderContainer edge regions
                    var header= new ContentPane({
                        region: "top",
                        "class": "edgePanel",
                        content: "Header content (top)",
                        splitter: true
                    });



                    /* Menú */
                    var contentMenu = new ContentPane({
                        region: "left",
                        id: "leftCol", 
                        "class": "edgePanel",
                        content: "",
                        padding:0,
                        splitter: true
                    });

                    var aContainer=new AccordionContainer({style:"height: 300px"}, "markup");
                        aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
                            title: "Contact",
                            content: "Hi!"
                        }));
                        aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
                            title:"Work",
                            content:"Hi how are you?"
                        }));
                    contentMenu.addChild(aContainer);



                    **var tabs=new ContentPane({
                        href: "list.php",
                        title: "Lista"
                    });**
                    contentTabs.addChild(tabs);



                    appLayout.addChild(header);
                    appLayout.addChild(contentMenu);

                    appLayout.addChild(contentTabs);






                      //aContainer.startup();
                    /*contentAcordion= new AccordionContainer({
                        min-size:20,
                        region:'leading,
                        splitter:true,
                        id:'leftAccordion'
                    });*/

                    // start up and do layout
                    appLayout.startup();










                    var cells = [
                      [
                        new gridCells.RowIndex({ width: "10%" }),
                        { name: "Column 1", field: "col1", width: "30%" },
                        { name: "Column 2", field: "col2", width: "30%" },
                        { name: "Column 3", field: "col3", width: "30%" }
                      ]
                    ];

                    gridLayout = [{
                            type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector"
                        }, 
                        cells
                    ];

                    var data = [
                        { id: 0, col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: "new", col4: "But are not followed by two hexadecimal"},
                        { id: 1, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "new", col4: "Because a % sign always indicates"},
                        { id: 2, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "read", col4: "Signs can be selectively"},
                        { id: 3, col1: "note", col2: false, col3: "read", col4: "However the reserved characters"},
                        { id: 4, col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "It is therefore necessary"},
                        { id: 5, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "To problems of corruption by"},
                        { id: 6, col1: "note", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "Which would simply be awkward in"}
                    ];

                    var grid = new DataGrid({
                    //store: test_store,
                    structure: cells,
                    rowSelector: "20px",
                    "class": "grid"
                    }, "grid");
                    grid.startup();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works successfull, and load a list.php.

In list.php I have a code for create a grid, If i execute individually it works and show the grids successfully:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: Progammatic Layout</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="grid" class="demoLayout"></div>

        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script>
            require([
                "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                "dojox/grid/cells",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(DataGrid, gridCells, Memory, ObjectStore, baseArray, lang, _CheckBoxSelector){
                var cells = [
                    [
                        new gridCells.RowIndex({ width: "10%" }),
                        { name: "Column 1", field: "col1", width: "30%" },
                        { name: "Column 2", field: "col2", width: "30%" },
                        { name: "Column 3", field: "col3", width: "30%" }
                    ],[
                        { name: "Column 4", field: "col4", colSpan: 4 }
                    ]
                ];

                gridLayout = [{
                    // First, our view using the _CheckBoxSelector custom type
                        type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector"
                    }, 
                    cells
                ];

                var data = [
                    { id: 0, col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: "new", col4: "But are not followed by two hexadecimal"},
                    { id: 1, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "new", col4: "Because a % sign always indicates"},
                    { id: 2, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "read", col4: "Signs can be selectively"},
                    { id: 3, col1: "note", col2: false, col3: "read", col4: "However the reserved characters"},
                    { id: 4, col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "It is therefore necessary"},
                    { id: 5, col1: "important", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "To problems of corruption by"},
                    { id: 6, col1: "note", col2: false, col3: "replied", col4: "Which would simply be awkward in"}
                ];

                var objectStore = new Memory({data:data});

                var test_store = new ObjectStore({objectStore: objectStore});

                // create the grids.
                var grid = new DataGrid({
                    store: test_store,
                    structure: cells,
                    rowSelector: "20px",
                    "class": "grid"
                }, "grid");
                grid.startup();

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if I call index.php the grid doesn't show, how can I do this? why is the reason, no no javascript execute?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to move away from the 'how do you solve the current problem' and try to answer 'how do you satisfy your requirement'.

To do that I'm assuming that your grid contents will eventually be dynamic and delivered on demand. If this is the case, put all your grid building code into your initial page load, and use xhrGet to fetch just the data to populate the data object (but see later paragraph to save unnecessary coding).

Data should be delivered from your php code as a json stringified object (build the array to deliver from php then use `json_encode(utf8_encode(data_array))`

IIRC (its been a while) You should just be able pass the url as a parameter to the data object which services the grid, and if the return data is in the right format, it should load and display it automatically.

look at 
itemFileReadStore - dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html

You'll fine an exsmple about half-way down the page using grid. If your intention is to send the data back to the server or someghow allow it to be changed iin the client, you may want to use itemFileWriteSore instead. Personally I always used to use it, just in case I needed it. The overhead is minimal.

If your code is likely to want to re-read the gridded data after the page has loaded, then you will need to jump through a couple more hoops, but it's still fairly easy to do.

Caveat .. I'm thinking in Zend 1.11, dojo 1.4 terms here ... but the principles are going to be the same ... its fundamental to dojo so I doubt they've changed object data stores that much :)

Comment: I'm trying to do a backend. In a future I will need load an save from MySQL server, but now it is not the question

My problem is how can I structure a program. I have a various sections in this backend for administrate various DB objects. This objects have a list and the edit element form with tabs.

My Idea are load a file for any section, example:contacts.php. In this file I will like to put the code for the list of this contacts and the form for edit one element when i select one of this elements. 

This is not valid way? How you, do this? You Know a site to tell how structure a dojo site?

Comment: That's a much broader question outside the scope of the original program. I'm afraid everything I leaned happened by doing it and refining my technique so I'm not much use for recommending tutorial sites, but the dojo documentation ( http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/ ) is very good and the site is filled with tutorials and examples. I suggest you start there and work outwards.

Comment: David - look at list.php - starting from the definition of objectStore. You use locally generated data to populate the store, but with itemFileWriteStore, it is possible to specify a URL instead of the raw data. For testing, the url could just be a text file containing pre-defined json which is retrieved by the store. The store will acquire the data by calling the url. Later in the development you can replace the call to the json file with a call to a php file which generates the json dynamically ... I hope that makes sense, sometimes my explanations are a bit confused.